# Powershell and .NET5.0 fails loading the assembly

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, .net-5

**Background**

Using visual studio 2019 v16.10.3 I have created this (standard MS example source) class library and successfully compiled into MyMathLib.DLL

```
using System;

namespace MyMathLib
{
    public class Methods
    {
        public Methods()
        {
        }
        public static int Sum(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
        public int Product(int a, int b)
        {
            return a * b;
        }
    }
}
```

My MyMathLib.csproj file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

And then I want to try executing this code using powershell using the following script:

```
[string]$assemblyPath='S:\Sources\ResearchHans\DotNetFromPowerShell\MyMathLib\MyMathLib\bin\Debug\net5.0\MyMathLib.dll'
Add-Type -Path $assemblyPath
```

When I run this I get an error, and ask what's going on by querying the error for `LoaderExceptions`:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> S:\Sources\ResearchHans\DotNetFromPowerShell\TestDirectCSharpScript2.ps1
Add-Type : Kan een of meer van de gevraagde typen niet laden. Haal de LoaderExceptions-eigenschap op voor meer informatie.
At S:\Sources\ResearchHans\DotNetFromPowerShell\TestDirectCSharpScript2.ps1:2 char:1
+ Add-Type -Path $assemblyPath
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], ReflectionTypeLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
 

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $Error[0].Exception.LoaderExceptions
Kan bestand of assembly System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a of een van de afhankelijkhed
en hiervan niet laden. Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

(Sorry for dutch windows messages: something like "Cannot load one or more of the types" and the loader exception  Cannot load file or assembly "System.Runtime" etc...

I have seen many related issues on SO, but they are usually quite old and do not refer to .NET5.0

**This works**

When I directly compile the example source like below, it works just fine.

```
$code = @"
using System;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class Responder
    {
        public static void StaticRespond()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Static Response");
        }

        public void Respond()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Instance Respond");
        }
    }
}
"@

# Check the type has not been previously added within the session, otherwise an exception is raised
if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]'MyNameSpace.Responder').Type)
{
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp;
}

[MyNameSpace.Responder]::StaticRespond();

$instance = New-Object MyNameSpace.Responder;
$instance.Respond();
```

**Why?**

The whole Idea to have a proof of concept that I can utilize my .NET5 libraries using e.g. powershell scripts. I actually have to load a much more complicated assembly, but this oversimplified example seems to be my primary issue at the moment.

**The question**

What am I missing? - How do I get this to work?

TIA for bearing with me.

Comment: Do you build your assembly on a x64 arch ? In which mode (x86_64 ? x64 only ?) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't state what version of Powershell that you're using. However, I can reproduce the error by the following.

In VS 2019, create a `Class Library` (C# Windows Library).

[image]

Rename the class from "Class1.cs" to "Methods.cs"

**Methods.cs**

```
using System;

namespace MyMathLib
{
    public class Methods
    {
        public int Sum(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
        public int Product(int a, int b)
        {
            return a * b;
        }
    }
}
```

Compile.

- Open `Windows Powershell`
- Type: `(Get-Host).version`

[image]

Then type the following:

```
PS C:\Users\Test> [string]$assemblyPath="C:\Temp\MyMathLib.dll"
PS C:\Users\Test> Add-Type -Path $assemblyPath
```

which results in the following error:

```
Add-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -Path $assemblyPath
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], ReflectionTypeLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

This occurs because .NETCore 5 isn't supported by Windows Powershell 5.1 - only on versions 6 and above. For Powershell 5.1 or below, it's necessary to use .NETFramework instead.

See [Resolving PowerShell module assembly dependency conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/resolving-dependency-conflicts?view=powershell-7.1) which states the following:

> PowerShell and .NET
> ... In general, PowerShell 5.1 and below run on .NET Framework, while PowerShell 6 and above run on .NET Core. These two
> implementations of .NET load and handle assemblies differently.

See [Installing PowerShell on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-7.1) for how to get the latest version of Powershell.

In `Powershell 7.1.3`, one can call a method from MyMathLib.dll by doing the following:

```
PS C:\Users\Test> [string]$assemblyPath="C:\Temp\MyMathLib.dll"
PS C:\Users\Test> Add-Type -Path $assemblyPath
PS C:\Users\Test> $m1 = New-Object -TypeName MyMathLib.Methods
PS C:\Users\Test> $m1.Sum(2,3)
```

**Note**: Since the class/methods aren't static, it's necessary to create an instance by using `$m1 = New-Object -TypeName MyMathLib.Methods`

However, if it's static (as shown below):

**MyMathLib.cs**

```
using System;

namespace MyMathLib
{
    public static class Methods
    {
        public static int Sum(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
        public static int Product(int a, int b)
        {
            return a * b;
        }
    }
}
```

Then one can do the following in Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\Test> [string]$assemblyPath="C:\Temp\MyMathLib.dll"
PS C:\Users\Test> Add-Type -Path $assemblyPath
PS C:\Users\Test> [MyMathLib.Methods]::Sum(3,2)
```

Comment: Indeed upgrading to powershell 7 did the trick. I Assumed Win10 auto - update gives me latest updates on Powershell too. Re-experiended that assumption is the mother of all f:ups. Thx!