# PowerShell CmdLet with NET8 could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying an experiment and I want to create a `CmdLet` for `PowerShell` in `NET8`. I have created a new `Class Library` and added the following packages:

- Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK
- PowerShellStandard.Library

as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211358/how-to-automate-either-powershell-or-powershell-core-for-same-machine/58211901#58211901). Then, I added this code to create the `CmdLet`:

```
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace PowerShellCmdLet
{
    [Cmdlet("Get", "Test")]
    public class TestClass : Cmdlet
    {
        protected override void BeginProcessing()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BeginProcessing");
        }
    }
}
```

When I open `PowerShell` on the project `bin` directory, I import my dll with

```
Import-Module .\PowerShellCmdLet.dll
```

but then I get this error:

> Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Management.Automation, Version=7.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified. At line:1 char:1
> Import-Module .\PowerShellCmdLet.dll
>
> ```
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
> ```

I tried to open `PowerShell` as an administrator but I get the same issue.

Comment: When you say you "open PowerShell", you're talking about `powershell.exe`, not `pwsh.exe`? `powershell.exe` only hosts Windows PowerShell 5.1, which is built on .NET Framework. It'll never be able to load your .NET 8 assembly.

Comment: I tried both and I get the same error

Comment: And what version of `pwsh.exe` are you running? `"$($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)"`

Comment: The powershell version should match the System.Management.Automation version. So you should have atleast 7.4 installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell and .NET5.0 fails loading the assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68350410/powershell-and-net5-0-fails-loading-the-assembly)

Comment: @user246821 I saw this post, but it has not resolved my issue. In my case, I'm creating a `CmdLet` for PowerShell, not a library to use as a type.

Comment: Did you click on the URLs in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68352130/10024425) and read them?

Comment: @user246821 yes, but I'm doing something different

Answer (score 1):

i used the package: System.Management.Automation" Version="7.4.1" to build the dll.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="System.Management.Automation" Version="7.4.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then using pwsh v 7.4.1, i can load the dll successfully and run the command

```
Import-Module path/to/PowerShellCmdLet.dll
#call the command
Get-Test
```

output:

```
BeginProcessing
```

Poweshell ISE can not load the dll because it does not support net8

If you are using VS code, you can run it, because vs code use pwsh if it is installed.